# Sending large files reliably over Bonjure Logic question

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, networking, bonjour

I want to send large files over Bonjure network. When I send a file from one device to another in Bonjure I have to split the file in to NSData packets and sent them to the other device. How do I make sure that all the packets arrive at the destination, and if a packet doesn't arrive there how do I tell the first device to resend it? Can you help me out with the logic or some example code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a modified version of the open source [BeamIt](http://arctouch.com/beamit/) code to send audio files between devices. The basic procedure is to use ACK packets to acknowledge the receipt of a packet. Check out a network book for the standard protocol, then check out BeamIt to get you started on the right path.